# Xamarin forms new solution startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I'm just barely learning Xamarin forms for Cross platform development.

It seems kind flakey,

Every time I start a new project, I immediately have to update the packages... that's okay. but then I have to go manually update the projects references to point to the new version of the packages that just got installed.

Then add a dependency to Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.9

then nugget install these packages..

Install-Package Xamarin.Forms -Version 3.6.0.264807 (latest at time of writing)

Install-Package NETStandard.Library -Version 2.0.3

Only then will my brand new vs2017 xamarin forms cross-platform app "hello world" actually compile.

There has to be an easier way to go from "create project" to "hello world"

what is the official correct process that I'm supposed to be doing instead.

Comment: That's way more work than usual. Updating nuget packages is usually the only thing needed.  All I've ever had to do was go to nuget pacakage manager for the solution, install the updates, compile and go. Are you waiting for the nuget package manger to finish restoring the packages before trying to update or compile?

Comment: Yep, it got that list by starting the new project, then googling each error as I get them.

Comment: just did it' again, 16 errors, including not able to find system.

Comment: I think I've got it down to 3 steps now, update/wait, uninstall Xamarin.Forms  from main project , reinstall Xamarin.Forms .
Then it will compile, but I don't' get the manual install right after updating the same package.